# "Thus, the sum of a + b may be re-written as 2a + 1" . . . How?

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

Right, hi everyone. Sometime ago in the not too distant past, I downloaded a short paper titled 'Basic Proof Techniques' written by David Ferry (I will drop the link  below). Long story short, Ferry goes over 4-types of proof: Direct Proof, Proof by Contradiction, Proof by Induction and Proof by Contrapositive. In order to demonstrate how each proof unfolds, he uses the theorem: *If a and b are consecutive integers, then the sum of a + b is odd.* Ok, fine.

Now's a splendid time to announce that math and I go together like England and the Euro's go together...we don't. That said, here is his direct proof of the theorem:

'Proof. Assume that a and b are consecutive integers. Because a and b are
consecutive we know that b = a + 1. **Thus, the sum a + b may be re-written as
2a + 1.** Thus, there exists a number k such that a + b = 2k + 1 so the sum a + b
is odd.'

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the bolded sentence (I bolded it for emphasis). For example, let's say a = 2 and b = 3 (as 2,3 are consecutive integers) 3 = 2 + 1. So, 2 (a) + 3 (b) = 5 and 2(2) + 1 = 5 also. BUT HOW??? WHERE AND WHY DOES THE '2' COME INTO PLAY?!?!?!? Perhaps this question is too vague to be given a precise answer, but it has given me an absolute massive headache (one too massive to not be asked on this forum).

I must depart now for food, so thanks in advance for everyone's help...appreciate it greatly I do!

Edit:
Here is the Link: [https://www.cse.wustl.edu/~cytron/547Pages/f14/IntroToProofs_Final.pdf](https://www.cse.wustl.edu/%7Ecytron/547Pages/f14/IntroToProofs_Final.pdf)

Comment: If $b=a+1$ then $a+b=a+(a+1)=(a+a)+1=2a+1$.  We have used the fact that addition is associative.

Comment: The numbers are consecutive.  So if the smaller one is $a$ and the larger one is $b$ then because the are consecutive $b = a+1$.  So if we write $a+b$ and we substitute $a+1$ for $b$ we get $a+ b = a+ (a+1) = 2a + 1$.  That's all.  An example $a = 17$ and $b =18$.  According to this $a + b = 17 + 18 = 35$ must be that $17 + 18 = 2\times 17 + 1$.  SO let's see.... $2\times 17 + 1 = 34 + 1 = 35$.... Well looky there.  It works.  And it makes sense... After all $17 + 18 = 17 + (17 + 1) = (17+17) + 1 = 2\times 17 + 1$.

Comment: fleablood - I gotcha, boss...that makes a tad more sense. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2 + 3 = 2+(2 + 1) = (2 + 2) + 1 = 2\times 2 + 1$.

And $17 + 18 = 17 + (17 + 1) = (17+17) + 1 = 2\times 17 + 1$.

And if $a = a$ and $b = a+1$ then

$a + b = a + (a+1) = (a+a) + 1 = 2a + 1$.